# NIntegrate 3D Interpolation function in a region extracted from ListContourPlot3D

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, regions

I have a list of 3D volumetric data points, e.g. for every position in 3D space there is a value. What I want to do is to firstly use "Interpolation" to get a function form of the data f[x,y,z] and do an integral within a region. The region is the enclosed region by some contour (say, f[x,y,z]==0.5) of that function. What I do is that I use "ListContourPlot3D" to find the contour that I want and use "BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics" to get the region enclosed by it. However, when I want to integrate it with "NIntegrate" it doesn't work out. Although there is no error reported, it run for a long time and end up with just printing the "NIntegrate" command. I tried to play with the integrate method and "AccuracyGoal". When I decrease the AccuracyGoal to only 1, it works for some region, but I need a relatively accurate result than that. I wonder why it doesn't work and how to fix it or if there is other ways to do it?

Another weird thing is that what I use "NItegrate" to integrate the interpolation function in a polyhedral region got by using "DelaunayMesh", it works well.

Pictures below shows a typical region within which I want to integrate. The Yellow spherical one is the result of "ListContourPlot3D" and blue region is got by using "BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics". Example of "NIntegrate" results for the polyhedral region (which works) and the contour region (which doesn't work) are also shown below.

I have been trying to figure something out for days and have no idea what to do. I will extremely appreciate it if somebody can help me with this.

[image: Result of "ListContourPlot3D"]

[image: Result after using "BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics" on the contour]

[image: Successful "NItegrate" in polyhedral region]

[image: The failed one which doesn't give you number]

```
    DIso = ListContourPlot3D[Domain, Contours -> {0.0}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.7]}, 
  PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Detailed"}, 
  DataRange -> {{0.5*dx, Lx - 0.5*dx}, {0.5*dy, Ly - 0.5*dy}, {0.5*dz,
      Lz - 0.5*dz}}, Mesh -> None, MaxPlotPoints -> 100, 
  BoxRatios -> {Lx - dx, Ly - dy, Lz - dz}, ImageSize -> 500(*,
  Axes\[Rule]False*)]
region = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[DIso]
profile = Import["/Users/xiejiayu/Downloads/phD.dat"];
profile = Flatten[profile];
(*Assign values to "Extra" points outside the boundary in each \
direction by using periodic boundary condition to improve the \
precision*)
Extra = 30;
profileData0 = 
  Flatten[Table[{{(x + 0.5)*dx, (y + 0.5)*dy, (z + 0.5)*dz}, 
     phiAB[[(Which[z < 0, z + Nz, z >= Nz, z - Nz, True, z]*Ny + 
          Which[y < 0, y + Ny, y >= Ny, y - Ny, True, y])*Nx + 
       Which[x < 0, x + Nx, x >= Nx, x - Nx, True, x] + 
       1]]}, {z, -Extra, Nz - 1 + Extra, 1}, {y, -Extra, 
     Ny - 1 + Extra, 1}, {x, -Extra, Nx - 1 + Extra, 1}], 2];
(*
Interpolate phi and Integrate over the Wigner-Seitz cell.
*)
f0 = Interpolation[profileData0, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  Method -> "Spline"]
f = Interpolation[profileData, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  Method -> "Spline"]
R = ImplicitRegion[
  f0[xj, yj, zj] >= 
    0 && (xj - Lx)^2 + (yj - Ly)^2 + (zj - Lz)^2 < (Lx/2)^2, {xj, yj, 
   zj}]
NIntegrate[f[xi, yi, zi], {xi, yi, zi} \[Element] R, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 10]/Abs[Volume[R]]
```

Comment: Everything is clear, but it’s better to insert a piece of code instead of pictures.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. I will add the code on